# Rotating elements in JS - how should I change my JS code?

Tags: javascript

I know where the bug is but how can I change it? the positon of clock's hand in deg?

```
    <script>
        var secondHand = document.querySelector('.second-hand');

        function setDate() {
            var now = new Date();
            var seconds = now.getSeconds();
            var min = now.getMinutes();
            var hour = now.getHours();
            var secondsDegrees = ((seconds / 60) * 360) + 90;
            secondHand.style.transform = "rotate(secondsDegrees)deg)";                 console.log(seconds);
        };
        setInterval(setDate, 1000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Create a fiddle please

Comment: codeshare is ok?

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5zlmEN

Comment: Your string concat is wrong, it should be secondHand.style.transform = "rotate(" + secondsDegrees + "deg)";

Comment: 2 hours fighting ... ;) Thanks a lot!

Comment: To be honest I didn't think about it as a string :)

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a static string, when you probably want to concatenate. As Thijs pointed out you can use the `+` operator to concatenate strings, or you can use [ES6 Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) like my example below.

```js
var secondHand = document.querySelector('.second-hand');

function setDate() {
  var now = new Date();
  var seconds = now.getSeconds();
  var min = now.getMinutes();
  var hour = now.getHours();
  var secondsDegrees = ((seconds / 60) * 360) + 90;
  secondHand.style.transform = `rotate(${secondsDegrees}deg)`;
}
setInterval(setDate, 1000);
setDate();
```

```css
.container {
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
}

.second-hand {
  margin-top: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="second-hand">Hand</div>
</div>
```

I don't know what your HTML/CSS looks like so I made my own for this demonstration.

Comment: WOW Thanks! `rotate(${secondsDegrees}deg)` looks good! but I need some time to lern/remind ES6 ... :)

Comment: @PaulK If this answers your question, considering clicking the gray checkmark to make it green and mark it as the accepted answer.